# MDX hierarchy level AVG

Tags: ssas, mdx

i have a dimension hierarchy:

```
B - C - D - E
```

and one measure:

```
measures.eur
```

If i make calculated member:

```
AVG([hierarchy].[All],[Measures].[eur])
```

i can get single average from all hierarchy members in the *top level* of hierarchy. 
But i want to have different average calculated from *every level* of the hierarchy.

So that when selecting hierarchy member C it shows the AVG of all the C's in the hierarchy,
when selecting B it's AVG of all B's and so forth..

I tried:

```
 AVG(
 [HIERARCHY].PARENT,
[Measures].[eur]      
)
```

But it's not giving the average for *all the members* on the hierarchy levels, but it's very close to what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following expression using the level function :

```
AVG ( [selected-member-of-c].level.members, [Measures].[eur] )
```